# how to creat a hi low python code

Tags: python-3.x

You have been asked to write a program to keep children of all ages busy on a long trip.  The program will allow the user to play the high/low game on a computer.  The program will ask the user how many games he/she want to play, then generate a random number from 1-64 inclusive (different for each game).  The user will have 6 tries to guess it.  If the user’s guess is too high or too low, the computer will tell them which and allow the user another guess until 6 guesses have been exceeded.  If the user guesses the correct number, the program will say so and not ask for anymore guesses for that game.  At the end of the last game, the software will display how many games were won and what percent were won to 3 decimal places.

I am new to python and programming in general, I do not know how to create the program so that the user can play multiple games and at the end of however many games they choose to play, Im not sure how to write the program to tell the percentage of games won to the total played.

this is what i have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
games= int(input("How many games do you want to play? ")) #asking user how             many games he or she would like to play

#instructions      
print("\n")
print("I am thinking of a number in the range of 1-64 inclusive.")
print(" You have 6 tries to guess it.")
print("\n")


import random    
x=(random.randint(1,64))
tries=0
guess=0

while guess != x and tries < 6:
    tries= tries + 1
    guess= int(input("What is your guess? "))

    if guess > x:
        print("Sorry your guess was too high.")
    if guess < x:
        print("Sorry your guess was too low.")
    if guess == x: 
        print("Congrats, you are a winner!!")

if guess == x:
    print(" You won")


if guess != x:
    print("Sorry, you lose!! The number was",x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the code for your game in a loop, adding new variables to keep track of how many individual games were won/lost/played (you only need any 2 of the 3 to compute the percentage won), although it would be cleaner to put the code for playing a single game in a function (if you've learned about them), which is nice way of separating the two aspects of the program.